# Unhandled Exception in C# (System.IO.IOException)

Tags: c#, exception, bitmap, ioexception

I use to get the next exception when reading/writing to a dead socket connection:

`System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation on non-blocking socket would block`

Yet I can't catch it in the catch section of try-catch. Any ideas? It says `Unhandled Exception`..

This is the code:

```
try
{
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(CommunicationHandler.GetStream());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is System.IO.IOException)
        {
            //Some code which is unreachable..
        }
}
```

I don't think that it has to do something with the `Bitmap` obj, but some sort of an Exception that can't be caught. It seems like the program doesn't even enter the catch section.

Comment: Is there any more code or just this one? Are you sure the `Exception` appears in that line?

Comment: Yes, this is what the debugger says.. @RonaldoAraújoAlves

Comment: It should be technically impossible to have an unhandled exception in a general catch-all `catch (Exception ex)` like that. What if you specifically catch the `IOException` first? You can catch multiple exception types, you know.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, your code should work. Here are some cases for you to check:

- The exception is not of type System.IO.IOException. Check the documentation, a quick search found [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream)). It could be a custom exception.If you have the possibility you can check the type of the Exception also like this:

  ex.GetType();
- If you say you are not hitting the catch block, are you sure you are not calling async method, which is not awaited somewhere?

Comment: I tried the first option with `ex.ToString()`, but as the debugger says, it was unhandled.. And could you please explain about the other option? I did not really get what you mean.

Comment: Try the ex.GetType(); which will return the exact type of the exception and see if it really is System.IO.IOException. ex.ToString() creates and returns a string representation of the current exception, which you don't need in that case.

The second thing I mentioned is that if you are writing asynchronous code or simply calling async methods somewhere in the try block, there is a chance that something is throwing an exception and you are not entering the catch block. Although this is less likely.

Give more information if you can, if neither of this helps.

Cheers